# Is there a quick way to convert Eclipse "libraries" to Maven POM entries?

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, dependencies, dependency-management

I've got an eclipse project with several "libraries", each containing a significant number (35-40) of individual jar files.  For instance, a JBoss "library" will generally have several hundred .jar file associated with a particular runtime.

Is there a way to find/use the "library" objects with Maven so that I can specify them in my POM.xml, or am I stuck with individual entries for each individual .jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry Josh, think you're stuck.

We had this issue once (a legacy app with loads of jars that had to be moved to Maven) and what we did was write a little script that returned the SHA hash of all of the jar files, and searched the maven repository (given khmarbaise's link above) using that.  This way you know that you're getting the *exact* jar that you're already using.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution i can recommend is to use:

http://search.maven.org

For JBoss you need to use the search in JBoss repository.

https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html

But better check the documentation at JBoss if there is a more up-to-date source for JBoss.